# Npm test throws errors but app runs without errors

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, typescript, testbed

I have been working on an Angular 2/TypeScript application. Originally I had my application and unit tests running fine. But now I am getting errors when I run my unit tests.

```
Can't bind to 'closeOnSelect' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("label required">Versions</label>
          <select soho-dropdown noSearch name="versions" multiple [ERROR ->][closeOnSelect]="false" [(ngModel)]="selectedVersions">
```

Before I used the "closeOnSelect" attribute of the soho-dropdown element, my unit tests were running fine.

Note: the application works fine and this is an attribute of the soho-dropdown component but the unit test doesn't seem to recognize it.

I have tried importing the library as I did in my application but I get a different error when I do that, which I saw other people getting when they imported a library twice so I took it back out to show the root of this issue.

I can share my files, just let me know which ones. I didn't want to crowd the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated some version in my package.json and this resolved the issue.

I'm not sure which one of these in particular was causing the issue but my new versions are:

```
"@angular/common": "2.4.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
"@angular/core": "2.4.5",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.5",
"@angular/http": "2.4.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
"@angular/router": "3.4.5",
"@infor/sohoxi": "^4.2.5-develop",
"@infor/sohoxi-angular": "^4.2.5-develop",

"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.5",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.26"
```